# Order Creation from Flows

Tags: flow, visual-workflow

I have an flow which creates order from quote screen using a button on Quote.

But once the order is created it stays on Quote screen itself.
My requirement is once the order is created it should show up the order screen for newly created order?

Answer (score 0):

To make a flow end with the record that has been created by the flow it is necessary to use a visualforce page as it is not possible to pass the new record id to the calling button without using a variable within the flow and accessing it in the visualforce {!URLFOR('/variable name')}.

If you are using a VisualForce page and Controller you can set the finishlocation attribute to "{!URLFOR('/varRecordId')}" where the varRecordId is set in the flow as the Order's Salesforce Record Id. The varRecordId has to have the Input/Output Type set as Output. A custom controller is not necessary in this case just a minimal visualforce page.

```
   <apex:page>
    <flow:interview name="MyUniqueFlow" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/home/home.jsp')}"/>
</apex:page>
```

More detail in the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_finishlocation.htm).

See this useful [previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51498/help-with-finishlocation-on-flow) from SFSE